# God cannot start redis server. Getting this error: `/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid': Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, monitor, god

I'm trying to monitor a redis server with god (ruby gem). I changed the PID file path in /etc/redis/redis.conf to a rails app temp folder of the user deploying my app (using capistrano), and in the redis.god file I added the line "w.pid_file= ..." which points to the same PID path as the one I changed in the redis.conf file. So the redis.god file looks like this at the moment:

```
rails_env   = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
raise "Please specify RAILS_ENV." unless rails_env
rails_root  = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..'))

# Redis
%w{6379}.each do |port|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.dir           = "#{rails_root}"
    w.name          = "redis"
    w.interval      = 30.seconds
    w.start         = "/etc/init.d/redis-server start /etc/redis/redis.conf"
    w.stop          = "/etc/init.d/redis-server stop"
    w.restart       = "/etc/init.d/redis-server restart"
    w.start_grace   = 10.seconds
    w.restart_grace = 10.seconds
    w.log           = "#{rails_root}/log/redis.log"
    w.pid_file      = "/home/deployer/myapp/current/tmp/pids/redis-server.pid"

    w.behavior(:clean_pid_file)

    w.start_if do |start|
      start.condition(:process_running) do |c|
          c.interval = 5.seconds
          c.running = false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So the problem that I'm having is that god can get redis started. I looked at its log for the god file and it says the following:

```
Starting redis-server: touch: cannot touch `/var/run/redis/redis-server.pid': Permission denied
```

Why is it still trying to look in /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid? I changed the PID path in the redis.conf file to the new one shown above because I was getting Permission denied, but it is still insisting in looking in /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid. FYI, this where I got the idea to changed the PID path: [God configuration file to monitor existing processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426786/god-configuration-file-to-monitor-existing-processes)

Comment: It looks like you have a permission issue. If you have redis installed under sudo privilleges and runs under your user privilleges then no wonder it cannot touch file that belongs to root.

Comment: @daveTsunami Sure enough you that is true. I was under the impression that god would run with sudo powers and wouldn't be denied of permissions to its PID file. The way I fixed it was to change its w.start, w.stop, and w.retart lines to "usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf" <- for starting it. Make sure that you set in your redis.conf your pid and log file to a writable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have disabled SElinux 
you can disable selinux with this command:
 setenforce 0